# use '%' in output

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string-formatting

Probably a very simple problem and I have been looking for the answer but can not find the it, probably because i have not found out what to ask.

I want the following output, see the '%' character in the output:

> (33%)

i just do not understand how to format in the "%" character so it is seen in the output.

```
txt2 = [txt2 stringByAppendingFormat:@"(%i)", percentage];
```

I know that the above stringByAppendingFormat is wrong. I would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape it with another `%` so you get something like this:

```
txt2 = [txt2 stringByAppendingFormat:@"(%i%%)", percentage];
```

For a list of all format specifiers to use with the formatting functions, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).